# How can Sam appoint Bradley to be CEO?

Tags: tron-legacy

In the very end we Sam and Bradley talk and he asks him to be at Encom at 8am, but Bradley says,

> What about the board?

So how can Sam overrule the board?

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic, it's not about scifi. It's about how a certain fictional corporation works.

Answer (score 3):

Sam inherited what appears to be a [controlling stake](http://lexicon.ft.com/Term?term=controlling-stake%2Finterest) in his father's company. He simply chose not to exercise his voting rights until that point.

> *After his father vanished, **Sam inherited a huge stake in his company.
> But Sam didn’t care. He pretended the company didn’t exist,** except on
> one day every year—the anniversary of his father’s disappearance.*
>
> ...
>
> *Sam narrowed his eyes. Years ago, Alan had been his father’s best friend. After his father had escaped the digital world and focused back on the real world, he’d made Alan a partner at Encom. And when Kevin disappeared, Alan had been the one to help raise the young orphan. Now **Alan managed Sam’s majority ownership of the corporation—and he tried to manage Sam, too.***
>
> <sub><sup>[TRON: Legacy Junior Novel](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/TRON:_Legacy_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>